# joomla 3 - how to add/insert html pages in my site without iframe?

Tags: jhtml

I have on my pc a complete html site. It has an index page and 2 folders that have many pages. The index page has just links that link to pages in folder 1. Folder 1 has pages that have text, the text has links to pages in folder 2.

I added them to a simple component and succeeded to review the index page on the site. However, the links do not open folder1's pages, I get an error page on the browser that says that the request page is not found.

Steps of what I did:

Added my files (index page and 2 folders) in a folder called `mybook`. Moved it (mybook) to this folder in a component: **component\views\default\tmpl\mybook**.

Edited this file: **component\views\default\tmpl\default.php**

Added this code:

```
// [code not posted by OP]
```

Created a menu with this component, click on the menu, now mybook is on my joomla site .

BUT: the links inside mybook index.html (that links to pages inside folders) open an error page. The error is:

> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated.

Is there any help to make those urls works?

Note: I am not using iframe warber because:

opening any page inside the iframe does not reset the position to the top.

Explain: When using Joomla iframe, if scroll the iframe down and click on a link to open a new page, the iframe does not go to the start top of the page, but stays in its place, this forces the user to manually scroll to the top to see the start of the page (I hate this and my book has long pages) ...and other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

To simulate the structure of HTML files, to keep the same URLs, I suggest to:

- Create category/articles structure similar to the folder/files structure.
- Copy the HTML content into articles.
- Enable "Search Engine Friendly URLs".
- Enable "Use URL Rewriting".
- Fill in the alias field of articles with the corresponding file name.
- Enable "Add Suffix to URL".